# What is the difference between filterXpath and filter?

Tags: php, guzzle, goutte

I came accorss these when learning Goutte but I don't know how are they different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filterXPath` allows you to filter by an XPath expression, while `filter` allows you to filter by CSS selector.
Ex:

```
$crawler = $crawler->filterXPath('descendant-or-self::body/p');
$crawler = $crawler->filter('body > p');
```